# Why is the OCR&Vote disk group servicing SCAN name

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I have installed 11g R2 Grid Infrastructure followed by database software only installation. I have not created any database yet.

When I open asmca->diskgroup, I can see the diskgroup which I have created during grid installation. When I select that diskgroup->View Serviced Databases, what is the expected result? I am assuming it to be empty. But, in my case, I am seeing my Cluster name( SCAN name) as database name and used space is .26GB. Can somebody clarify on this. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: it will show you because you have not created any database ,, and if when you will create the database it will take your partition disk . hope it is help full to you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the Oracle Cluster Registry (OCR) where information about clusterware components is stored.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/rac.112/e41959/intro.htm#CWADD90952

Its size is 256 MB, or 0.26GB, you can check this with ocrcheck:

```
# ocrcheck
Status of Oracle Cluster Registry is as follows :
         Version                  :          3
         Total space (kbytes)     :     262120
         Used space (kbytes)      :       2948
         Available space (kbytes) :     259172
         ID                       : 1703252243
         Device/File Name         :       +OCR
                                    Device/File integrity check succeeded

                                    Device/File not configured

                                    Device/File not configured

                                    Device/File not configured

                                    Device/File not configured

         Cluster registry integrity check succeeded

         Logical corruption check succeeded
```